# How to display a ProgressDialog and dismiss it when finished doing a job

Tags: android, kotlin, progressdialog, android-library

I have a method which collects a large amount of data which slows down my application (all call logs). What I am trying to achieve is that before this method is called, it shows a `ProgressDialog`, this I have achieved. What I am not capable of is that it makes it dismiss when the method gets all the data and displays it on the screen.

For this method I am using the [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) library to make the call to the asynchronous method.

This is my code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = MyActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    var pd = ProgressDialog(this)
    pd.show()
    pd.setContentView(R.layout.myCustomLoading)
    pd.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparent)
    pd.setCancelable(false)

    doAsync { //Anko library

        val myList = getData()  //This methood return a List<Model>
        binding.list.adapter = MyAdapter(this@MyActivity, myList)

    }

    pd.dismiss()
}
```

The problems I have with this code is that the ProgressDialog is not showing and to display the data on the screen in the RecyclerView I must touch the screen or drag it, this is rare.

Comment: First try moving pd.show() after pd.setCancelable(false), you set the layout after calling show(), so it has no Content to display at that point.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed this, but still can't dismiss my ProgressDialog and still the problem with the data showing in screen :(

Comment: Try to dismiss pd and update adapter with "uiThread {" inside "doAsync"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `pd.dismiss()` to the bottom of async block.

But don't forget to run it on UI thread `activity.runOnUiThread { pd.dismiss() }`